# With several widgets sharing the same signal slot (event handler), how do I find out which one has been clicked?

Tags: qt

In my project I am using a  custom circle-shaped button widget derived from the QWidget class. I have added several of these widgets to a parent widget.

When one of these custom buttons is clicked, how do I find out which one was clicked?

Adding custom button to parent widget:

```
void ShotViewCTRL::addShot(QString shotNanme)
{
    ShotButton *btnShot=new ShotButton(this);
    btnShot->shotName=shotNanme;

    connect(btnShot,SIGNAL(Shot_Selected()),this,SLOT(SHOT_CLICKED()));
    btnShot->CreateButton();
    btnShot->show();

}
```

My parent widget is **ShotViewCTRL** (inherits from QWidget), the child widget is **ShotButton** (custom control, inherits from QWidget).

The control is working fine. It's sending sending to parent object. In my problem, I added the same custom control 10 times.

I need to find which control was clicked? Please help me find the solution.

I have referred to the Qt documentation to find the child widget, but I did't understand. Some sample code would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QSignalMapper` is what you are looking for. With QSignalMapper, you can add something like an Id (or even a pointer to the QButton itself) as additional data to the signal emittance and you have to adjust your slot so it takes additional data (ID or Pointer).

Then either distinguish in the slot itself by the id you give your *objects* some virtual function type() so you can distinguish with that or even try casting and catch errors (Tip: don't try the last method, it may work differently on different compiler).

Comment: In the button click signal, i passed the button id to find the which button clicked. it's working fine. i have one more question. how to bring the object into front? because i have lot of widgets is there. when i click any one i need to bring into front. now i got which widget is clicked but, i can;t able bring to front. you have idea how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by bring to front? Focus?

Comment: Bring to front in the sense, the controls are overlapped. when i click the control, it's should come to front. the control fully visible from the overlap state.

Comment: create a new question with a screenshot as this seems to be something *bigger* I still don't get the point.
Don't forget to accept a answer as your initial question seems solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`QObject::Sender`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qobject.html#sender) function to find which `QObject` sends the signal. Regarding the first warning in the doc, it's what you are searching for.

Comment: DO NOT use QObject::Sender, this is breaking the OOP principle of Qt

Comment: it's working. i have one more question. how to bring the object into front? because i have lot of widgets is there. when i click any one i need to bring into front. now i got which widget is clicked but, i can;t able bring to front. you have idea how to do that.

Comment: Using QObject::sender() is fine -- also simple, efficient, and to the point. There's no downside to using it at all.

Answer (score 0):

you specify different slots for different buttons with same signal.with that you can recognize the different button click

Comment: no. this buttons are created in run time. may be, number of buttons will go up to 100 also. so i can't write different slot for each and every thing. i need to use the single slot to receive this.

Comment: these buttons are of same class name or different? if you are having different class name then use QString className = current->metaObject()->className(); to get the class name for differentiation

Comment: also, keep an ID in button to differentiate each button and check it in slot to get to know which button emitted the signal.